# Значення слова «обоюдожалий» у вірші Стуса

Tags: значення-слів

Послухав цю пісню, [The Frunk – Пам'яті Василя Стуса](https://youtu.be/hoaQ_e-v_gA), і знайшов один із складових віршів.

Яке значення може мати це слово, "обоюдожалий"? Я розумію, що це неологізм - але з яких слів він складений і як приблизно можна зрозуміти сенс?

"Той край, який обожнює, і це взаємно"?

> Як тихо на землі! Як тихо!
> І як нестерпно — без небес!
> Пантрує нас за лихом лихо,
> щоб і не вмер і не воскрес.
> Ця Богом послана Голгота
> веде у паділ, не до гір.
> І тінь блукає потаймир,
> щовбами сновигає потай.
> Пощо, недоле осоружна,
> оця прострація покор?
> Ця дума, як стріла, натужна,
> оцих волань охриплий хор?
> Та мури, мов із мертвих всталі,
> похмуро мовили: чекай,
> ще обрадіє із печалі
> твій **обоюдожалий** край.

(У пісні співається трохи не так - "ще встане із печалі твій випалений край")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> <sub>Запитник</sub>
>
> Я розумію, що це неологізм

Так, перша поява в творї Василя Стуса [*Як тихо на землі! Як тихо!*](//stus.center/p/iak-tikho-na-zemli-iak-tikho-21369), текст котрого і наведений в запитаннї. Якщо вдати ся в точнїший термін, то це радше [*оказіоналізм*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%96%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BC_(%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F)):

> <sub>Українська Вікіпедія</sub>
>
> Оказіоналі́зми (авторський неологізм) — мовленнєві одиниці, які утворюються за стандартними та новими словотвірними моделями, з характерним експресивним забарвленням та індивідуальним характером.

---

> <sub>Запитник</sub>
>
> з яких слів він складений

Тут очевидно, що з [*обоюд*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) + сполучний *-о-* + [*жало*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE) + прикметникове закінчення *-ий*.

---

> <sub>Запитник</sub>
>
> як приблизно можна зрозуміти сенс

[*Обоюдний*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) це, так, *взаємно*, але радше основне значення, хоч і рїдше, *з двох чогось* (*сторін*, *боків* ітд). Англійською це *mutual* або радше [*bilateral*](//dictionary.com/browse/bilateral).

[*Жало*](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE) (англ. *sting, cutting edge*) в значенні *гострий кінець* (*зброї*, *інструменту*).

Тобто, смисл: ***вгострене з двох сторін***; англ. *stinged* (*sword* or here *by sword*) *from two sides*.

Праця [*Тематична група оксиморонів із семантичним наповненням радість/смуток у поезії Василя Стуса*](https://journals.indexcopernicus.com/api/file/viewByFileId/1208584.pdf) (Інна Перцова) навіть наводить джерело алюзії — [*Кобзарь*](//uk.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0:%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_(1876).djvu/655) Тараса Шевченка і пояснює до чого тут жала.

> На конотативному рівні, що утворює підтекстний смисл образу краю, який *обрадіє із печалі*, формується його символічне значення, що ускладнюється алюзіями з поезії Тараса Шевченка та Біблії:
>
> > *Яко Бог кара неправих*, 
> > *Правим помагає*; 
> > *Преподобниї во славі* 
> > *І на тихих ложах* 
> > *Радуються, славословлять*, 
> > *Хвалять имя Боже*; 
> > *І мечі в руках їх добрі*, 
> > ***острі обоюду***
>
> У Шевченка мова йде про меч, гострий з обох сторін. У Стуса звертає на себе увагу авторське новоутворення *обоюдожалий*, значення якого актуалізується асоціативними звʼязками із цими рядками Кобзаря. Україна у поета — трагедійна держава, від якої відвернувся Бог (*Ця Богом послана [Голгота](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B0)*). *Оцих волань охриплий хор* — охриплий, бо молитви не чує Господь. Тож, очевидно, що один гострий кінець меча від Всевишнього. Інший гострий дотик — від тоталітарної держави, що завдала неоправного удару українській культурі та народові.

Тобто тут можна грубо тлумачити, що край має *жало з двох сторін*, але [можливо тут] є ніянс.

Comment: А чи немає тут певної гри слів, може друга частина цього слова не від _жало_, а від _жаль_, як у словах _жалібний, жалоба_?

Comment: @YellowSky не̂, бо тоді бѫло би _обоз́альиь_, нп. _синь_ → _синьиь_,  (проти _жалиь_, _зелен_ → _зелениь_ ітд). Те, з́е не маьить мьакого в *з́алоба*, це радс́е, гадаьѫ, вплив _-о-_. Переве̂рити складно, бо *-о-ба* не дѫз́е продѫктивниь, ьак _-ь-ба_. Моз́на такоз́ зазнац́ити, с́ц́о такі прикметники зазвиц́аь маьѫть наросток _-евиь_: _сталь_ → _сталевиь_ (_сталиь_ во̂д _ста-ти_), _бо̂ль_ → _болевиь_, _ґель_ → _ґелевиь_, _нѫль_ → _нѫлевиь_; або _-ниь_… ітд. Зве̂сно, моз́ливо Твоьа правда, але тоді треба ц́имо-сь по̂дкре̂пити.